# c++ Interlocked Ops On WinXP

Tags: c++, node.js, windows-xp

I am trying to build nodejs 8.5 for win xp .. I found that v8_base_2 project file runtime_atomics.cc defines few macros that use `Interlocked[,And,Or,Add,..][8,16,32,..]` functions that require Windows 8+

The doc. for many of these functions says that the execution of these functions will prevent multiple threads from accessing the same var.

What I want to know: "Does the execution of these functions really prevent multiple threads from accessing the **same var** **OR** the **same location** of the variable?"

If it's preventing the same var. not the location, then is there any implementation for these operation that is platform independent or at least compatible with XP

especially operation for 8bit operands

Comment: I believe that all those functions are available as intrinsics in Visual Studio.  See, e.g., [_InterlockedOr Intrinsic Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/interlockedor-intrinsic-functions).

Comment: but whats the difference between _Interlocked[..] and Interloced[..] functions at runtime

Comment: Under normal circumstances they're exactly the same: InterlockedX() is just a macro for _InterlockedX() which will work on any operating system.  I'm not sure what's happening in your scenario.  It might help if you could explain what error message you get.

Comment: I did not get any err msg .. but when I changed platform toolset to v140_xp these macros where undefined thats all.

Comment: so I defined them and currently rebuilding the code .. and waiting for errs

Answer (score 2):

"same var OR the same location" suggests a distinction that C++ does not make. An object is a location in memory with a certain type. And given `InterlockedIncrement`, the type is already restricted to an integral type.

Ultimately, these functions perform a bus-locked read-modify-write. That indeed prevents other threads from interfering.

Comment: what made me asking for whether "same var. or same loc." that the signature of the func. contains volatile for the first arg. that confused my knowledge about c/c++

Comment: @Ala'a.H: That's indeed possible - it's a Microsoft-specific thing. In Standard C++, you'd use `std::atomic<int>::operator++`.

Answer (score 1):

MSalters has already described the behaviour of these functions.

As for implementation, assuming you are using Visual Studio, then if for some reason the usual macros for the `InterlockedXxx` functions aren't available, you can use the corresponding `_InterlockedXxx` intrinsics instead.  Because these depend only on the CPU, not the operating system, they should work as expected even in a Windows XP build.

If you prefer to minimize modifications to the code, you could copy the relevant section from the `winnt.h` header directly into your application.